# Do I need to create a special column family for counter columns?

Tags: api, cassandra, thrift

My question concerns Cassandra 0.8 and Pelops. I found that Pelops uses the same Thrift command for reading a slice of columns as for a slice of counter columns. Then, it iterates over the retrieved collection of a Thrift ColumnOrSuperColumn objects, asserting that column (or counter_column) field is not null. It seems to be obvious that for mixed column family, execution of either of these methods will fail.

So, does Cassandra require that all of the columns in a column family are to be of the same type?

The following code is a fragment of Selector class from Pelops.

```
private List<Column> getColumnsFromRow(final ColumnParent colParent, final Bytes rowKey, final SlicePredicate colPredicate, final ConsistencyLevel cLevel) throws PelopsException {
    IOperation<List<Column>> operation = new IOperation<List<Column>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Column> execute(IPooledConnection conn) throws Exception {
            List<ColumnOrSuperColumn> apiResult = conn.getAPI().get_slice(safeGetRowKey(rowKey), colParent, colPredicate, cLevel);
            return toColumnList(apiResult);
        }
    };
    return tryOperation(operation);
}

private List<CounterColumn> getCounterColumnsFromRow(final ColumnParent colParent, final Bytes rowKey, final SlicePredicate colPredicate, final ConsistencyLevel cLevel) throws PelopsException {
    IOperation<List<CounterColumn>> operation = new IOperation<List<CounterColumn>>() {
        @Override
        public List<CounterColumn> execute(IPooledConnection conn) throws Exception {
            List<ColumnOrSuperColumn> apiResult = conn.getAPI().get_slice(safeGetRowKey(rowKey), colParent, colPredicate, cLevel);
            return toCounterColumnList(apiResult);
        }
    };
    return tryOperation(operation);
}

private static List<Column> toColumnList(List<ColumnOrSuperColumn> coscList) {
    List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>(coscList.size());
    for (ColumnOrSuperColumn cosc : coscList) {
        assert cosc.column != null : "The column should not be null";
        columns.add(cosc.column);
    }
    return columns;
}

private static List<CounterColumn> toCounterColumnList(List<ColumnOrSuperColumn> coscList) {
    List<CounterColumn> columns = new ArrayList<CounterColumn>(coscList.size());
    for (ColumnOrSuperColumn cosc : coscList) {
        assert cosc.counter_column != null : "The column should not be null";
        columns.add(cosc.counter_column);
    }
    return columns;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, does Cassandra require that all of
>   the columns in a column family are to
>   be of the same type?

Yes, in the sense that currently it does require that a CF contain all counters or all non-counters. However,

- [This will change](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2614), possibly as soon as 0.8.1
- non-counters definitely do not have to be of the same data type (bytes, long, utf8, etc. can all be mixed in the same row)